# Can I bound this $N((1+\delta)^{2N}+1)\leq N^j$? for any $j\in \mathbb{N}$, where $\delta<1$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

For $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough. Can I bound this $N((1+\delta)^{2N}+1)\leq N^j$ for any $j\in \mathbb{N}$, where $\delta<1/2$? I tried using Matlab for j=5, but I'd like some ideas for a proof. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if $N=1$?

Comment: I forgot to put for $N$ large enough

Comment: For fixed  $\delta\gt 0$, the function $(1+\delta)^{2N}$ grows faster than any polynomial in $N$.  When it overtakes $N^j$ is not pleasant to find, but can be described in terms of the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: for example for $N=2$,  $j=5$ and $\delta=0.07$, $2((1+0.07)^4+1)<2^5$

Comment: The answer is "No" because, for every $\delta>0$ and every $j$, $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N((1+\delta)^{2N}+1)}{N^j}=+\infty.$$